# How do I remove all files in a directory, but not sub-folders, or their contents in linux?

Tags: linux

I have a directly called /cache which has about a million files.

I restructured my caching system to put cache files into different folders, inside the /cache dir. new cache files are already being written to those sub-folders. So I want to remove all the files inside the /cache dir that are not in any subfolder.

How would I do this in SSH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do so with the `find` command.

```
find /cache -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I suggest to take a look to the list of files which would be deleted before executing `find` in combination with `-exec rm`:

```
find /cache -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

This will give you the list of files without deleting them. Again; use `find` in combination with `-exec rm` with caution, I can't be clear enough :).

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove all files in cache folder without removing files in directory in cache folder ?
If it is, you can use find : `find /cache -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete`
-maxdepth limits the depth and don't remove files in folders